# FBConnect Crashes my app on login

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, fbconnect

I am trying to Connect my app with the FBConnect ,but it crashes every time.
It takes all the previous credientials and then it crash after login..
I need to connect my with this so that when it login my app should open then.

my code is

```
- (void)session:(FBSession*)session didLogin:(FBUID)uid {
    NSString* fql = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                 @"select uid,name from user where uid == %lld", self.usersession.uid];
    NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fql forKey:@"query"];
    [[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.fql.query" params:params];
    self.post=YES;
    self.usersession =session;
    NSLog(@"User with id %lld logged in.", uid);
    [self getFacebookName];
}
```

**Error**

```
2012-12-31 11:13:16.522 Project[296:11c03] User with id 10000456096786 logged in.
2012-12-31 11:13:16.922 Project[296:11c03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
** First throw call stack:
(0x17c5052 0x1c58d0a 0x17b1db8 0xa0d5 0x6ed14 0x6f477 0xffea59 0xffce94 0xffdeb7 0xffce4f 0xffcfd5 0xf41f6a 0x20febbd 0x21cb5ea 0x21cb8b5 0x20f5298 0x21cb16b 0x20f5137 0x179997f 0x16fcb73 0x16fc454 0x16fbdb4 0x16fbccb 0x2473879 0x247393e 0x609a9b 0x27c8 0x2725)
```

and if i enter my code in `session didlogin` to enter in app after success login.
it crash with same thing...

```
- (void)session:(FBSession*)session didLogin:(FBUID)uid {


    NSString* fql = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                 @"select uid,name from user where uid == %lld", self.usersession.uid];
    NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fql forKey:@"query"];
    [[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.fql.query" params:params];
    self.post=YES;

    self.usersession =session;
    NSLog(@"User with id %lld logged in.", uid);


    AppDelegate *appdelegte =(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    [[[appdelegte navigationController] view]removeFromSuperview];

    [[appdelegte window]addSubview:[[appdelegte tabBarController]view]];

    [[appdelegte tabBarController]setSelectedIndex:0];


    [self getFacebookName];
}

- (void)getFacebookName {
NSString* fql = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                 @"select uid,name from user where uid == %lld", self.usersession.uid];
NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fql forKey:@"query"];
[[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.fql.query" params:params];
self.post=YES;
}
```

Comment: show getFacebookName method

Comment: What line are you crashing?

Comment: @Prince check now code...I have edited

Comment: @Luda it actually completes the..session didlogin then getFacebookName and then moves to `- (BOOL)resume {` in `FBSession.m` and after 20 push pop method then crashes

Comment: @Prince if i remove the fb lines from the `session`method it gives nslog logged in id- then,`Error`-this endpoint has been deprecated .to temporary reenable it,you may disable the "august_2012"platform migration.IT will BE PERMANENTLY DISABLED ON august 1,2012`..

Comment: @Luda can u check ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354191/facebook-ios-sdk-3-0-8-crash-xcode-on-alternative-login

Comment: @Prince can u check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354191/facebook-ios-sdk-3-0-8-crash-xcode-on-alternative-login