# Facebook-Ios-Sdk 3.0.8 Crash Xcode on Alternative Login

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using `Facebook-ios-sdk 3.0.8` to login in my app. it works fines on the first time  and gives me the `Username` from the `FbGraph` but It crashes the Xcode in my next login..
what would be reason...please check code and let me know...

```
- (IBAction)buttonClickHandler:(id)sender {
// get the app delegate so that we can access the session property
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

// this button's job is to flip-flop the session from open to closed
if (appDelegate.session.isOpen) {

    [appDelegate.session closeAndClearTokenInformation];

} else {
    if (appDelegate.session.state != FBSessionStateCreated) {

        appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
    }


    [FBSession.activeSession openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView

                        completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,

                                            FBSessionState state,

                                            NSError *error) {
                            // and here we make sure to update our UX according to the new session state
                            [self updateView];
                            NSLog(@" state=%d",state);

                            [FBRequestConnection
                             startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                               id<FBGraphUser> user,
                                                               NSError *error) {

                                 userInfo = @"";

                                 // Example: typed access (name)
                                 // - no special permissions required
                                 userInfo = user.username;

                                 NSLog(@"string %@", userInfo); 


                             }];




                        }];    } 


}
```

**first login Output**

```
2013-01-16 13:56:35.613 facebooktest[2690:f803]  state=513
2013-01-16 13:56:36.335 facebooktest[2690:f803] string christien.101012
```

**below output on next login**

```
 2013-01-16 13:56:42.747 facebooktest[2690:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.facebook.sdk:InvalidOperationException', reason: 'FBSession: an attempt was made to open an already opened or closed session'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x15ca052 0x175bd0a 0x15c9f11 0x1249f 0x3043 0x15cbec9 0x11b5c2 0x11b55a 0x1c0b76 0x1c103f 0x1c02fe 0x140a30 0x140c56 0x127384 0x11aaa9 0x14b4fa9 0x159e1c5 0x1503022 0x150190a 0x1500db4 0x1500ccb 0x14b3879 0x14b393e 0x118a9b 0x1e38 0x1d95 0x1)
```

and ** what would be the difference between **

```
[FBSession.activeSession openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView

                        completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,

                                            FBSessionState state,

                                            NSError *error)
```

and

```
 [appDelegate.session openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView

                        completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,

                                            FBSessionState state,

                                            NSError *error)
```

in simple words `appDelegate.session` and `FBSession.activeSession` because if i use `appDelegate.session` instead of that it does not gives me the `user.username` and not crash ...and i use `FBSession.activeSession` it gives me the `user.username` for the first time then on next time it crashes..

Comment: Wait, why are you logging in twice?

Comment: the event goes likes `login-logout-login(crash)` means after logout I am logging...

Comment: Ah, okay. Well I would make sure that when you're showing your login view again after logging out, you're not creating a loop because you didn't properly dismiss the earlier session. What I mean is that Facebook does an animation when it logs in; you might as well view that animation as a modal segue. You need to dismiss this segue before presenting another login view...

Comment: ok if i use `[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
            FBSession.activeSession=nil;` to dismiss it should be work right...

Comment: Yeah, but you also need to make sure that where you are within your current view hierarchy checks out as well.

Comment: `[FBSession setActiveSession:nil];` after calling `closeAndClearTokenInformation` resolved my issues with repeated opening session flow